# A Simple R Loop

Tags: r, for-loop, rep

I was wondering **how to make a simple "loop" to create 21 vertical lines** in my plot using "**segments()**" command?

Specifically, I want the 21 vertical lines to be equally spaced going **from** **21 consecutive points on the X axis** all to **1** **on the Y axis**. So, for example for the "**first vertical line**" and the "**last "vertical line**" the R code is:

```
m<- seq(0,1,by=.05)
segments(c(0,1),c(0,0),c(0,1),c(1,1),col="red")
```

Comment: `segments(m, 0, m , 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the word "loop" in quotation marks; I assume that a plain segments() command rather than a true for loop is what you're looking for.

```
m = seq(0, 1, length.out=21)    # make 21 equally spaced numbers between 0 and 1
plot.new()                      # make a new plot device (delete if using an existing plot)
segments(m, 0, m, 1, col="red") # draw the red line segments
```

That should make 21 vertical lines.